# Reading from file

Tags: python, file-io

I am a beginner and just started learning Python couple days ago (yay!)

so i've come across a problem. when i run, this code outputs everything but the text (txt in file is numbers 0-10 on seperate lines)

```
def output():
    xf=open("data.txt", "r")
    print xf
    print("opened, printing now")
    for line in xf:
        print(xf.read())
        print("and\n")
    xf.close()
    print("closed, done printing")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should print out each number on its own line, like you want, in a lot less code, and more readable.

```
def output():
    f = open('data.txt', 'r').read()
    print f
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't use `line`, try:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

Answer (score 1):

When you used `for line in xf:` you basically already iterated over the file, implicitly reading each line.

All you need to do is print it:

```
for line in xf:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you aren't seeing the line output is because you aren't telling it to output the line. While iterating over values of `line`, you print `xf.read()`. The following is your function rewritten with this in mind. Also added is the use of a [with statment](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) block to automatically close the file when you're done with it.

(Using `xf.close()` is not wrong, just less pythonic for this example.)

```
def output(): 
    with open("data.txt", "r") as xf:
        print xf 
        print("opened, printing now") 
        for line in xf: 
            print(line) 
            print("and\n")
    print("closed, done printing")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have read the line of text into the variable line in the code `for line in xf:` so you need to show that e.g. print(line)

I would look at tutorials like the [python.org](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) one